# Has anyone published a plan for how to modernize the American voting system?

Tags: united-states, voting-systems, electoral-college, federalism

It’s been said that the American voting system is a relic of the past, with idiosyncratic features due to political negotiations and compromises at the time it was formed. Let’s say in a modern country an election for representatives should be simple: everybody has easy access to a ballot, there’s a clear and non-corrupt ballot counting process, and whoever gets the most votes wins. I’m specifically highlighting the electoral college system by which the popular vote is not a determining factor in the election.

Has anyone outlined a plan given the political mechanism that be for how to reform this voting system?

I mean someone with a reasonable level of expertise outlining a sequence of steps for the most likely way to achieve this reform.

Comment: By "modernize", you mean doing away with the Electoral College for the Presidential election, and just going to a full popular vote?

Comment: Can you make it more explicit if you’re asking about plans to modernize the American election system or plans to implement _a specific plan of modernization_ which you should outline

Comment: This could use some prior research. The topic is pretty vast https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Electoral_College#Efforts_to_abolish_or_reform

Comment: Step number 1 would be to establish consensus that there is a need to get rid of the electoral college.  While there is a strong support for that in certain political circles, it's not that clear that it is supported widely enough to gain any traction.  I am guessing that establishing consensus, as step 1, is not something that you are looking for in an answer. Or am I wrong?

Comment: All sorts of people have created revisions of the current electoral system: some reasonable, some iffy.  I've put some real thought into the idea myself. However, electoral revisions are a pragmatic (near) impossibility. People who have the power to make such changes got their power because they worked the current system well. Changing the system would cost them power, and while a wise, conscientious, socially responsible individual might sacrifice power for the greater good, not a lot of those make it into office.

Comment: You don't need a "plan".  You just follow the constitution, which is pretty explicit on how it can be amended.

Comment: I suspect that a lot of those with power and influence would be afraid of any change. Once you start amending the constitution people might ask for more, like  a two rounds election which might help overcome the current dominance of the two major parties.

Comment: It isn't actually obvious that direct election of the president would be *better* than the indirect election via electors. Lots of modern democracies use Westminster-style parliaments, which effectively use a similar system to elect the head of the executive; it's just that the "electors" (members of parliament) also have other duties than voting for the prime minister. Certainly I don't think the current US electoral college system is the best possible system (and it utterly fails to work the way its creators wanted it to work), but it isn't clear that a direct national vote would be either.

Comment: "Has anyone outlined a plan given the political mechanism that be for how to reform this voting system?" This is too unspecific. There are probably thousands of such plans. Please limit the scope of the question a bit, like what kind of plans you are most interested in or if maybe you only want to know the most positively received of these plans or the simplest of these plans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proposals to change / eliminate the Electoral College system have been made many times, starting shortly after the Constitution was first written.

Many changes have been made within each state. Only two states (Main and Nebraska) maintain even a bare semblance of how the framers of the Constitution envisioned selection of the President would work. The original intent was that the people would vote in each congressional district for a sane person (i.e., a rich white man) to make the selection for them. The candidates for President wouldn't even be on the ballot. The people would instead be voting for electors. That concept never took hold; even in states where people explicitly voted for Electors rather than President, the Electors made their choice very clear. In many states it is now illegal for an Elector to vote other than the way the state voted for President.

One of the key changes made over time by the states was to make the electors be a state-wide bloc. (Maine and Nebraska are the only exceptions.) The intended consequence was to give a given state more power in who would become President. This had unintended consequences. It gave more power to states with small populations. It gave even more power to states where the vote is predicted to be close (the "swing states").

Eliminating the Electoral College would require either a constitutional amendment or a compact between states that makes the Electoral College moot. Getting a constitutional amendment is intentionally very hard. One key hurdle is that 3/4 or more of the states must agree to a proposed amendment. This means that only thirteen states would be needed to reject a proposal to eliminate the Electoral College. There are well over thirteen states that are over-represented in terms of population in the Electoral College. Add in the highly populated swing states that benefit from presidential candidate promises and there is zero chance of eliminating the Electoral College.

The political impossibility of eliminating the Electoral College (at least for now) leaves making the Electoral College moot as the only alternative. There is a movement underfoot to do just that, the [National Popular Vote Interstate Compact (NPVIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Popular_Vote_Interstate_Compact). The idea is that the signatory states will chose their Electors based on the candidate who won the nationwide popular vote. Sufficient state support for this compact isn't there yet. Whether this compact would be legal is a matter of debate. Suppose the NPVIC does garner enough support from the states. Now suppose that a decade later people in some key signatory states vote against the popular candidate, and suppose that that states in question have legislatures that want to reject the original support of the compact. Would that original support stick? This will be a nasty fight that goes to the Supreme Court. It's a dicy proposition.

Comment: What about increasing the size of the Electoral College and also adjust proportions of it? Doesn't sound that like a quick hack that could be implemented relatively fast? And could it make the outcome closer to an outcome of a popular vote?

Comment: @Trilarion The size of the college is in the Constitution: the number of senators, representatives, plus three for DC.

Comment: Doing what you said would require accepting a new state (Puerto Rico, for example), splitting an existing state into multiple states (e.g. California or Texas, where there are proposals to do just that in both states), or changing the size of the House, which despite a tripling of the population has been stuck at 435 since 1910. The first two would add senators. The last option would make the House of Representatives more representative. None of these seem likely, but none require a change to the Constitution.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So increasing the number of representatives sounds like an obvious approach (short of changing the constitution).

Comment: @Trilarion Four states have been admitted to the union since the last time the size of the House was changed. While changing the size of the House does not require a Constitutional amendment, it does require approval by the House, the Senate, and the President. One party would inevitably gain power while the other would inevitably lose power. Good luck with that!

Comment: Didn't say it's easy, but certainly the bar is lower than for any change in the constitution. Also having control of both houses of Congress and the presidency has happened in the past. As long as they don't also need the Supreme Court, I would think it could have happened already, if people really wanted it. Number of representatives could be much higher by now. Just as an example: UK Parliament has 650 constituencies for a much smaller population.